# How to redirect all links to new site with same domain & same content?

Tags: google-search-console, url, 301-redirect

Is the same domain but i change url structure and website platform and is important to save all traffic from old links.

Comment: Why didn't you include all the information from your comments on Stack Overflow?   I'll ask again here:  what did you change?

Comment: Which platform (webserver and CMS) is your system running on?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Apache webserver with activated `mod_alias`, you can use [RedirectPermanent](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent)-Rules in your `.htaccess`/vHost-config:

```
RedirectPermanent /old/url /foo/bar
```

This specific rule only works with Apache version greater or equal to `2.2.6`. In older versions, the second URL should be an absolute URL.

The above affects all requests to URIs beginning with `/old/url`. It strips the `/old/url` prefix, and replaces it with `/foo/bar`. So `/old/url/qux/index.html` would be redirected to `/foo/bar/qux/index.html`.

You can add one `RedirectPermanent` directive for each URL that needs to be redirected, but if possible, try to leverage the prefix matching to save some rules. If the `RedirectPermanent` isn't mighty enough for your purposes, consider using `RedirectMatch` or `mod_rewrite`.